# How do I add an array to a list?

Tags: c++, list, stl

I have an array called *vertices*, it's declaration is as follows:

```
  CPoint vertices[11];
```

Then I have a list called _m_ElementList_

```
  std::list<CPoint[11]> m_ElementList;
```

Using *AddElement()* I want to add elements to this list, each element being an array of *CPoint* objects(i.e of the same type as vertices)

```
void AddElement(CPoint* vertices)
   { m_ElementList.push_back(vertices); }
```

---

For some reason that's not working, it's telling me that no instance of the function matches the argument list- why's this and what should I do?

Comment: since it's a problem when the argument type doesn't match the list item type, why not, say, make the argument type match the list item type.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth That's precisely my question! How should I pass the array to the function? I've tried `void AddElement(CPoint vertices[11])`- but, well, it doesn't work.

Comment: a raw array isn't copyable, so it's ungood as list element. but you can wrap it in a `struct`. or better, use a `std::array` which does that for you, or if you need variable length, use a `std::vector` (at some cost but not very much).

Comment: anyway, the declaration `void AddElement(CPoint vertices[11])` is rewritten to just `void AddElement(CPoint vertices[])` which is rewritten to just `void AddElement(CPoint* vertices)`, so it's *equivalent* to the original... that's inheritance from early C. a very ungood part of the C++ type system, to say the least! :-)

Answer (score 3):

The *idea* of working with raw arrays and pointers is wrong to begin with. You're already using `std::list` (i.e you seem to know about standard containers), then why not use `std::vector<CPoint>` also? It would make your life easy:

```
std::list<std::vector<CPoint>> m_ElementList;
```

and then :

```
void AddElement(std::vector<CPoint> vertices)  //C++11
{ 
    m_ElementList.push_back(std::move(vertices));  //move
}
```

If your compiler doesn't support C++11, then pass by reference as:

```
void AddElement(std::vector<CPoint> const & vertices) //C++03
{ 
    m_ElementList.push_back(vertices);  //copy
}
```

As a sidenote, I think `AddVertices` would be a better name.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to an array either as the array itself or as a pointer to the first element. For example:

```
CPoint vertices[11];

// address of the first element
p_vertices = &vertices;
```

or

```
// allocate
CPoint * vertices = new CPoint[11];

// deallocate
delete [] veritices;
```

If you take the latter approach you could simply declare your vector as:

```
std::vector<CPoint*> m_elementList
```

and insertion as:

```
void AddElement(CPoint* points) 
{ 
   m_elementList.push_back(points);
}
```

This also has a slight advantage if you ever need to change the number of points to something other than 11 because the dynamic allocation allows for a variable to be used in place of the constant. However, you'll want to carefully control access to the vector, the arrays it contains, and elements  in order to enforce correct usage.

BTW, its completely fine to mix and match STL and C-style pointers, especially if you're expecting to pass the data structure around quite a bit and copying of the elements is undesirable or expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
 std::list<CPoint[11]> m_ElementList;
```

you declare your list type wrong, the <> brackets define what TYPE the list holds, not how many elements, a proper declaration would be:

```
std::list<CPoint> m_ElementList;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem there is the brackets after the CPoint.  The purpose of the template is to provide the type of class (or more importantly, the size of the class), not the number.  Try:

```
std::list<CPoint> m_ElementList;
```